# Issues with ffmpeg hardware accelerated encoding and yadif

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a interlaced videos in mts container and would like to convert them to non-interlaced in mkv container, posibly in HEVC.

I tried following command line:

```
ffmpeg -y -hwaccel qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i "2008-07-13 00.08.47.mts" -c:v hevc_qsv -global_quality 20 -look_ahead 1 -vf yadif=1 "test.mkv"
```

And I get error:

```
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

When I remove `-vf yadif=1` everything works fine, I assume I need to tell ffmpeg that it needs to download/upload/convert the format from the iGPU back to memory for yadif to do the work and upload again, but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hwdownload-1

```
ffmpeg -y -hwaccel qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i "2008-07-13 00.08.47.mts" -c:v hevc_qsv -global_quality 20 -look_ahead 1 -vf hwdownload,format=nv12,yadif=1 "test.mkv"
```

Other HW accelerations.
https://nico-lab.net/combine_hw_decoder_filter_encoder_with_ffmpeg/

Comment: Actually this gives me errors like `[hevc_qsv @ 0x55c848b2f180] Selected ratecontrol mode is unsupported` and few others.

Comment: remove ```-look_ahead 1```  add ```-load_plugin hevc_hw``` .
```ffmpeg -y -hwaccel qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i "2008-07-13 00.08.47.mts" -vf hwdownload,format=nv12,yadif=1 -c:v hevc_qsv -global_quality 20 -load_plugin hevc_hw "test.mkv"```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the GPU-accelerated `vpp_qsv` filter in the transcoding chain, whose usage can be printed via:

```sh
ffmpeg -h filter=vpp_qsv
```

In your case above, the solution would be:

```sh
ffmpeg -threads 4 -y -fflags +genpts -init_hw_device qsv=hw \
-hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv \
-filter_hw_device hw -c:v h264_qsv \
-i "2008-07-13 00.08.47.mts" \
-vf "format=nv12|qsv,hwupload=extra_hw_frames=64,vpp_qsv=deinterlace=2:async_depth=4" \
-c:v hevc_qsv  -global_quality 20 "test.mkv"
```

**Explanation:**

For the video filter chain, see an extra argument `extra_hw_frames=64` passed to `hwupload`, needed by the MFX runtime which [requires a fixed frame pool size](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7120) to be pre-allocated. Use a number suitable to your requirements. Generally, you'll need a larger number (64, or thereabouts) if using features such as [look-ahead (LA-ICQ)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/advanced-bitrate-control-methods-in-intel-media-sdk).

The second filter in the chain is `vpp_qsv`, called up to perform advanced deinterlacing via the option `deinterlace=2`. In this flow, the decoding, transcoding and filtering (in this case, the deinterlacer) all run on the GPU. The option `async_depth=4` massively improves performance, as shown in [this commit message](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commit/89ffcd1bbe1150aa07ae52a4e1545668a4e83a3e).

[This](https://github.com/Intel-Media-SDK/MediaSDK/issues/2075#issuecomment-619379770) is why I omitted the `-lookahead 1` option (for now).
Should that change, I'll test and report back on the same.

According to [this](https://github.com/fulinjie/ffmpeg/commit/398f123b61736818d445f8a81c1d1848e1d57ddb) commit, look-ahead for the `hevc_qsv` encoder wrapper also requires extended bitrate control mode to be toggled on too, so the previous command with look-ahead would look like:

```sh
ffmpeg -threads 4 -y -fflags +genpts -init_hw_device qsv=hw \
-hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv \
-filter_hw_device hw -c:v h264_qsv \
-i "2008-07-13 00.08.47.mts" \
-vf "format=nv12|qsv,hwupload=extra_hw_frames=64,vpp_qsv=deinterlace=2:async_depth=4" \
-c:v hevc_qsv  -global_quality 20 -look_ahead 1 -extbrc 1 "test.mkv"
```

Kindly test and report back.

**Warning:**

Note that the SDK requires at least 2 threads to prevent deadlock, see [this](https://github.com/Intel-Media-SDK/MediaSDK/blob/master/_studio/mfx_lib/scheduler/linux/src/mfx_scheduler_core_ischeduler.cpp#L90-L93) code  block.